# A Trivial Pursuit #08 (Entertainment 2/4): Names

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, movies

<sub>This is part 8 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

Solve the fourteen rebuses below to find some names, then some names, then some names, then one final name - this is your answer...

[image: Fourteen rebuses]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First we solve the rebuses:

> ([Abu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Disney%27s_Aladdin_characters#Abu) - a = BU) + ([Ragu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rag%C3%BA) - a = RGU) + ([Andy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Murray) - a = NDY) = BURGUNDY

> (bark a->u = BURK) + [E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_Spain) = BURKE

> (cross - s = CROS) + (bike - k = BIE) = CROSBIE

> [DAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Quayle) + ([Cher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cher) - h = CER) = DANCER

> (grid d->f = GRIF) + FIN = GRIFFIN

> ([Hart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_Hart) - t = HAR) + ([PER sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_sign)) = HARPER

> keeper - e ^ n = KEPNER

> LA + PI + D + US = LAPIDUS

> ONE + (nil - n = IL) = ONEIL

> say ^ h = SHAY

> tab ^ u = TAUB

> TEN ([Dyson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Dyson) d->n = NYSON) = TENNYSON

> (web - b = WE) + ([Astley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) - t = asley) = WEASLEY

> W in KLE = WINKLE

Then we notice

> BURGUNDY and WEASLEY. Both have an orange outline and both are characters with first name Ron from *Anchorman: the Legend of Ron Burgundy* and *Harry Potter*. Then we see those movies' abbreviations in the middle square and both are italic. Turns out italic is movies and not-italic is TV shows.

We find them all:

> orange: Ron Burgundy ([*ATLOR?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchorman:_The_Legend_of_Ron_Burgundy)), Ron Weasley ([*HP*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter))

> green: Leslie Burke ([*BTT*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_to_Terabithia_(2007_film))), Leslie Crosbie ([*TL*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Letter_(1940_film))), Leslie Lapidus ([*SC*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie%27s_Choice_(film))), Leslie Shay ([CF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Fire_(TV_series))), Leslie Winkle ([TBBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory))

> red: April Dancer ([TGFU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_from_U.N.C.L.E.)), April Kepner ([GA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey%27s_Anatomy)), April O'Neil ([TMNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teenage_Mutant_Ninja_Turtles))

> blue: Chris Griffin ([FG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Guy)), Chris Taub ([H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_(TV_series)))

> yellow: Ben Harper ([MF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Family)), Ben Tennyson ([B1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_10))

Then we notice that

> Ron, Leslie, April, Chris, and Ben are all characters from [Parks and Recreation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parks_and_Recreation)!

I thought that was the end but @Daniel S observes in the comments that we can go further:

> let's take those characters' last names and order them by color of the rainbow:
>  red: April LU**D**GATE
>  orange: Ron S**W**ANSON
>  yellow: Ben W**Y**ATT
>  green: Leslie KNOP**E**
>  blue: Chris T**R**AEGER
>  If we index into the last name by the number of times the first name appeared in the grid, we get **DWYER**, the surname of the same show's character Andy Dwyer.

Comment: rot13(Lbh zvffrq gur ynfg gjb vgrengvbaf: Gur C&E punenpgref unir fheanzrf YHQTNGR, FJNAFBA, JLNGG, XABCXR, GENRTRE)

Comment: rot13(Vaqrkvat vagb gurfr ol gur ahzore bs bppheeraprf bs rnpu svefg anzr tvirf QJLRE (jubfr svefg anzr vf NAQL nf vaqvpngrq ol gur sbhe qbgf, gur ynfg bs juvpu vf terra))

Comment: rot13(...gubhtu V pna'g uryc ohg guvax gung gur qbg orsber gur terra bar fubhyq or pbybherq erq)

Comment: rot13(Nyfb whfg abgvprq gung gur rkgenpgvba beqre vf tvira ol envaobj beqrevat)

Comment: @DanielS, nice, the ordering and indexing makes sense, but I don't see what you're saying about the dots

Comment: rot13(Gur qnfurf vaqvpngr n svir yrggre anzr QJLRE, gur qbgf ner n purpx gb pbasvez gung g tbrf jvgu n sbhe yrggre anzr NAQL gur sbhegu yrggre bs juvpu vf L=TERRA (naq V guvax gung gur guveq fubhyq gurersber nyfb or Q=ERQ))

Comment: @DanielS, I believe the rot13(L pnzr sebz lryybj)

Comment: Your solution is spot on, well done :) The dots, however, were purely ornamental, intended to mimic a TV's green 'on' light, representing only that the answer is successfully found on the fourth iteration of names. No further significance to the character, sorry!

Comment: Also, I suspected beforehand that orange would be the breakthrough - glad it flowed so well for you!

Comment: @Stiv Thank you, it was fun. And Daniel S helped a lot. But I have to confess I don't really understand the flags and white areas under the dog...

Comment: Perhaps that would be more recognisable to a European - it's a blank licence plate...